# Why use content provider in one single app is not recommended

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, multiprocess

In Android Developers, it says that content provider is only recommended when you want to share data with other apps. But why use content provider in a single app is not recommended. I have two processes in my app and there is some data to share between them. I used to choose SharedPreferences with the flag MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, but it's not recommended too and is deprecated now. Anyone has some perfect solutions? And if I have to use content provider, will it cause performance problems?

Comment: Why are not you using SQLite database?

Comment: Also note that Content Providers are not considered as a type of storage. They just share the underlying storage.

Comment: A `ContentProvider` is `usually` backed by a database. Using shared prefs for such a task is not proper, neither is using `SharedPreference` with `ContentProviders`. This would be an `overkill`

Comment: @Skynet I think the user is asking why is that...

Comment: To share data between two apps, you can `write` to a `file` if you find `ContentProvider` too difficult. It is recommended to use a `ContentProvider` to share data between applications, but that is not the only use case. `ContentProvider` with `Loaders`, `SyncAdapter`  and `AccountManager` can be implemented to achieve flawless synchronization between the server and the app - that holds true even if the app does not share any data with other apps. A `ContentProvider` is also useful if your data is updating dynamically. You can set watchers. So yes it depends on your use case.

Comment: For a starter, you can check [this](https://github.com/spacecowboy/AndroidTutorialContentProvider)

Comment: The answer depends on lots of things, including: what do you want to share, how much of it, how frequently, how big it is, etc. But as others have commented, a ContentProvider might just be too much hassle for something that can be solved with a sql database, a waiting queue on some of the processes, an IntentService, etc.

Comment: @abforce I just need to storage some small data, like setting prefs. And I think SQLite database is not so proper

Comment: @AugustZhao So, definitely content provider is not proper too.

Comment: @Skynet I need to share some data between two processes in one app. Should this case be considered as two apps? I need watchers.

Comment: No under no circumstance this should be considered as sharing data between two apps. You can exemplify your use case with some code and illustration.

Comment: @Skynet OK. I have two processes. One contains a Service who is just there and do some background service. One contains some activities, and users can custom some preferences. When user change a preference in the foreground process, I hope the background Service can be notified and change its behaviour then tell the foreground that changes have been made. When the foreground activity receive the message, it changes the ui.

Comment: Finally, I found the answer on [android developers website](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html), in the "Using internal storage" part it says "If you want to share your data with other app processes, you might instead consider using a content provider, which offers read and write permissions to other apps and can make dynamic permission grants on a case-by-case basis.".